# How do I place a Google recaptcha in my website successfully?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, recaptcha

I am having real trouble putting a Google recaptcha into my website. There seems to be no easy to follow tutorial. I am brand new to JavaScript, but am building a website which receives a huge amount of spam from the contact form. I'd like a Google recaptcha form, possibly v2 as that seems the 'easiest' but I am still having issues.

I have PHP, JS and HTML and I am not understanding how any of it links, and it is not working. The form submits successfully, however, there is no way of telling the form has submitted, nothing happens on the page. I would like a Bootstrap success alert to take place when I press submit.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

    $Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
    $Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $email_from = "Your website";
    $email_subject = "You have a new submission form from Your website";
    $email_body = "First Name: $Fname.\n".
                    "Last Name: $Lname.\n".
                    "Email Address: $email.\n". 
                    "Telephone Number: $number.\n". 
                    "Company Name: $company.\n". 
                    "Message: $message.\n";

    $to = "howdy@yourwebsite.co.uk";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

    $captcha;
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){
        $email=$_POST['email'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['message'])){
        $message=$_POST['message'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
        echo '<h2>Please check the "I am not a robot" checkbox"</h2>';
        exit;
    }
    $secretKey = 'acombinationoflettersandnumbers';
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    // post request to the server
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . urlencode($secretKey) . '&response=' . urlencode($captcha);
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response, true);
    // should return JSON with success as true
    if($responseKeys["success"]) {

        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    } else {
        echo '<h2>This has been unsuccessful according to our security checks</h2>';
    }
?>
```

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form action="contact.php" id="contact-form" method="POST" role="form">
              <div class="messages"></div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_name">First Name*</label>
                    <input id="form_name" type="text" class="form-control" name="Fname" placeholder="David" required data-error='Please fill in your first name'>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_lastname">Last name*</label>
                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" class="form-control" name="Lname" placeholder="Beckham" required data-error="Please fill in your last name">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_email">Email address*</label>
                    <input id="form_email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="becks@example.com" required data-error="Please provide your email address">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_number">Contact number*</label>
                    <input id="form_number" type="number" class="form-control" name="number" placeholder="01234567890" required data-error="Please provide a contact number">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_company">Your company name</label>
                    <input id="form_company" type="text" class="form-control" name="company" placeholder="Ex-footballers r us">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_message">Your message*</label>
                    <textarea id="form_message" class="form-control" name="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="I need the world's best website...HELP!" required></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="acombinationoflettersandnumbers"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-brand btn-block" name="submit" value="Send enquiry">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
        'sitekey' : 'acombinationoflettersandnumbers'
      });
      };
      onloadCallback();

    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
      if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == "") {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("You can't proceed!");
    } else {
      alert("Thank you");
    }
    });
```

I have only got this far by following steps from lots of different tutorials and am not sure if any of it is correct. Hope someone is able to assist with a step by step process that allows me submit a contact form, with a success Bootstrap alert and form refresh once it has been submitted.

Thank you!

Comment: Dit my answer solve your problem?

Comment: I am still a little but confused as to where the JavaScript comes into this and where I would place the back-end code you have provided. I am very new to this and its all very confusing!

Comment: As far as I can see you don't need to use the javascript you provided!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

**front-end**

```
<div class="js-form-message form-group" style="text-align: center">
    <div style="display: inline-block;" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="yourkey"></div>
</div>
```

**back-end**

```
$url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretKey&response=$responseKey";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($response);
if ($response->success) {
 // not a robot
} else {
 // robot
}
```

The Recaptcha response will be placed in your `g-recaptcha` input tag. This value will be sent to the back-end (PHP) of the application. There you can validate the Recaptcha response and show a result based on the outcome of the Recaptcha.